# Updating MySQL 5.1 to 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, wampserver

I'm learning Ruby on Rails. I'm following a tutorial series to learn ROR4 and he's installing MySQL and MySQL gem.

But I already have

> Server version: 5.1.72-community - MySQL Community
> Server (GPL) Protocol version: 10
>
> Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12
>
> PHP extension: mysqli
>
> phpMyAdmin Version information: 4.0.4

which came along with WAMP 2.4. It's better to update to latest ones, but how can I update it and do I need to update? If not, how can I use ROR4 with WAMPServer? I'm kinda confused. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Who is "he"? Is it the tutorial series?

Comment: Yes the man giving the tutorial...lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL 5.1 is since December 31, 2013 [in the Oracle Sustaining Support](http://www.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html). This means if you have no special payed support contract with Oracle/MySQL you no longer get updates and patches. Therefore it is advised to upgrade to version 5.6 of MySQL.

If you have this installation just to learn Ruby on Rails you can keep it and follow the tutorial. But in this case you should check to get a MySQL gem that works with your version of MySQL.

Comment: I was using this installation for developing wordpress etc on localhost before. Now I have different projects that I want to build using Ruby on Rails, (I am new to ROR but it's really easy and I have a background on OOP) so I definitely need the 5.6. Do you think if I install 5.6 would my WAMPServer have any problems?

Comment: After you updated MySQL you may then update your drivers and after that you probably will need another PhpMyAdmin. This may happen or not. If you have installed your WAMPServer as one package you should check first if there is a newer package with all the needed versions inside.